# Calcular el producto mas vendido por categoria

Tags: sql

Teniendo estas 4 tablas:

```
TB_CAT_PRODUCTO (id_cat,nom_cat)
TB_PRODUCTO (id_pro,nom_pro,id_cant)
TB_PEDIDO (id_ped,fecha_ped
DETALLE_PEDIDO (id_ped,id_pro,cantidad,importe)
```

Como hallaria el producto mas vendido por categoria en un intervalo de tiempo?

Comment: GROUP BY, SUM y MAX son tus amigos.

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Answer (score -1):

Mira este ejemplo:

Para una tabla con cat,prod,cantidad puedes hacerlo así:

```
select max(suma),cat from 
  (select sum(cantidad) as suma, cat, pro from tabla group by cat,pro) as x
```

En tu caso debes construir la select interna haciendo las joins entre tus tablas.

Comment: te saludo y te comento lo ideal sería el ejemplo completo para guiar al OP en su duda, gracias por apoyar en la comunidad

Comment: Ni siquiera se ha molestado en compartir lo que ha intentado, con lo que se intuye que son trabajos que le han mandado en clase y no los quiere hacer, no respondas a preguntas que no tienen duda, solo deseo de ser respondidas.

Answer (score -1):

Primero que todo añadí el campo categoría a la tabla TB_PRODUCTO, declarando e insertando:

```
create table TB_CAT_PRODUCTO (id_cat  int,nom_cat varchar(25));
insert into TB_CAT_PRODUCTO values(1, "Audio");
insert into TB_CAT_PRODUCTO values(2, "Video");

create table TB_PRODUCTO (id_pro  int,nom_pro varchar(25), id_cat int);
insert into TB_PRODUCTO values(1, "VHS", 2);
insert into TB_PRODUCTO values(2, "DVD", 2);
insert into TB_PRODUCTO values(3, "iMAz", 1);
insert into TB_PRODUCTO values(4, "SoundTrack", 1);

create table TB_PEDIDO (id_ped  int,fecha_ped datetime);
insert into TB_PEDIDO values(1, "28-01-2019");
insert into TB_PEDIDO values(2, "29-01-2019");

create table DETALLE_PEDIDO (id_ped  int,id_pro int,cantidad int,importe int);
insert into DETALLE_PEDIDO values(1, 1, 1, 2000);
insert into DETALLE_PEDIDO values(1, 2, 1, 3000);
insert into DETALLE_PEDIDO values(2, 3, 2, 500);
insert into DETALLE_PEDIDO values(2, 4, 3, 700);
```

Haciendo el select:

```
select  
c.nom_cat
, MAX(d.cantidad)
from TB_PRODUCTO p
inner join TB_CAT_PRODUCTO c on p.id_cat = c.id_cat
inner join DETALLE_PEDIDO d on p.id_pro = d.id_pro
where c.nom_cat = "Audio"
```

Comment: Ni siquiera se ha molestado en compartir lo que ha intentado, con lo que se intuye que son trabajos que le han mandado en clase y no los quiere hacer, no respondas a preguntas que no tienen duda, solo deseo de ser respondidas.